# Set caret location to a specific line in a text control

Tags: java, swt

I have an input screen where the user types into an SWT Text control. As the user types I take the text, process it and show it in a separate read_only result text control. The length of the result text might be several characters longer than the input text.

I would like to position the resultant text control display so that it always shows the line where the user is currently typing in the input control.

I can get the input caret line using `ivTextInput.getCaretLineNumber()`, but there is no corresponding method to set the caret line number.

I can set the position of the caret in the result using `ivTextResult.setSelection(ivTextInput.getCaretPosition())` but the processing I do on the input text might "push" the result text down to the point where it is not visible without scrolling.

Ideally the result text display would marry-up with the input text display so that what/where the user types always lines up with the result text.

I have tried keeping track of the extra characters the processing adds, but the user can add text anywhere in the text control, and the resulting mess is un-usable, plus the way SWT text control handles new lines throws calculations off.

Comment: Possibly something using `Text.setTopIndex` to set the line at the top

Comment: Argh! I did NOT see that, and moreover would NOT have associated it with setting a line position. Thanks. I set it up as `ivTextResult.setTopIndex( ivTextInput.getCaretLineNumber() - 1 )` which works great

Answer (score 0):

`Text` has a `setTopIndex` method to set the line visible at the top of the control:

```
public void setTopIndex(int index)
```

Comment: Well, yes. As per the comments to the question, posted 12 hours before your answer.

Comment: Since it did what you want I posted this as an answer so that it would help other people

Comment: If a search is made (stackoverflow, Google, etc), would that search not include the question text and therefore lead the person to here? Where they would see the solution in the comments? Not trying to be snarky, its just that is how I would expect it to work, and thus not needing an "answer".

Comment: Comments are not permanent they may be deleted. People look for questions with answers.